# Can't run more than 2 paths with runpy

Tags: python, runpy

I have this code, the jogo==1 and jogo==2 options work fine and open what I want but the rest of the options dont open the .py files, is anything wrong with my code?

```
import runpy

def menuPrincipal():

  print("\nMenu\n")

  print("1 - Jogo do Galo")
  print("2 - 4 em linha")
  print("3 - Jogo da gloria")
  print("4 - Jogo da força")
  print("5 - Jogo Minas")
  print("6 - Sair")


while True:
  menuPrincipal()
  jogo = int(input("Escolha um jogo: "))

  if jogo == 1:
     runpy.run_path(path_name='jogoDoGalo.py')
  elif jogo == 2:
       runpy.run_path(path_name='jogo4emLinha.py')
  elif jogo == 3:
       runpy.run_path(path_name='jogoDaGloria.py')
  elif jogo == 4:
     runpy.run_path(path_name='jogoDaForca.py')
  elif jogo == 5:
       runpy.run_path(path_name='jogoMinas.py')
  elif jogo == 6:
       break
```

Comment: What do they do instead?

Comment: Looks ok to me. If there is an error message show the full traceback of it as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: When I select the other options they just repeat the menu again instead of running the files.

Comment: @MichaelButscher there is no error, the options just send the menu back again

Comment: Have you tried running any of those other files directly from the command line? What's the outcome? Also, are there any `if __name__ == "__main__":` lines it those files?

Comment: Maybe the other files are accidentally written in a way so that they (seem to) do nothing?

Comment: What happens if you put `runpy.run_path(path_name='jogoDaGloria.py')` outside the `while` loop and any `if` statements?

Comment: I runned "jogoMinas.py" in another file with runpy and it returned nothing, but its strange because when I run itself the code works just fine

Comment: @Arseny on the ones that work there is no `if __name__ == "__main__":` lines but on the ones that doesnt work are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a mere guess, but there might be code in those files that don't seem to run inside an `if __name__ == "__main__":` condition.

If that's the case, that code won't be executed when called via `runpy` because then those files will load into Python under module names different than `"__main__"`. Try removing the `if __name__ == "__main__":` condition.

Comment: It was this problem, I need to make some changes to the code to work after that but its ok, it is working now, thanks!

Comment: @BernardoPereira - Yw